# Deploying a Yii 2 app to a subdirectory of the document root

Tags: apache, web-deployment, yii2

I want to deploy a Yii 2 app to a website's subdirectory:

> http://example.com/subdirectory

My app's directory structure looks like this:

```
|-- LICENSE.md
|-- README.md
|-- assets
|-- commands
|-- components
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- config
|-- controllers
|-- mail
|-- models
|-- requirements.php
|-- runtime
|-- test.php
|-- test.txt
|-- tests
|-- vendor
|-- views
|-- web
|-- yii
`-- yii.bat
```

[According to Yii 2's documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html), for deployment you're supposed to rename the `web` folder to the document root of your server, like `public_html`, `wwww`, etc. Then you copy all the files to the parent directory of the document root. But nothing is said about how to deploy the app to a *subdirectory* of the document root.

The host is Apache, and I'm wondering if using an alias is the easiest way. I'm not sure from [the documentation on mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) which directive to use or where it should go, though.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I expected.

1. Move the `web` directory into your document root (e.g., `public_html`, `www`, etc.).
2. Rename the `web` directory how you want to appear after the domain name. For instance, if you want your app to live at `http://example.com/myapp`, then rename `web` to `myapp`.
3. Move your app's directory (which now should be minus the `web` subdirectory) one directory above your document root.
4. In the `web` directory, change the paths of the three `require` functions in `index.php`.

My modified `index.php` looks similar to the below. (If you copy and paste, remember to replace `your_app_name` with the name of your app's directory. Also note that I have multiple websites in my document root, so I have to get the parent of the parent of the parent of the `web` folder to make it out of the document root. Whew.)

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../../your_app_name/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../../your_app_name/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../../../your_app_name/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: I was about to point out that web is already a subdirectory :).

Comment: One little important note: My `.htaccess` file had `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` but in this case here it is important it is `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` (without the slash designating the root folder).